# Android : How can I move Edittext with soft keyboard , with out moving entire activity?

Tags: android, keyboard

I need to move edittext only with the soft keyboard with the all other view content being constant. i changed my android manifest android:windowSoftInputMode  field to "adjustNothing". But it will stop moving all the activity content together. I also tried getting soft keyboard height but not able to get a relievable way of doing it. Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Android has 2 methods of adjusting when the soft keyboard comes up:

- Resize the entire app to fit the remaining space.  The app will be scrolled if necessary so that the cursor is on screen.
- Pan the app, scrolling it so that the cursor is always visible.

There is no mode to make the edit text float up without changing anything else.  And there is no way to reliably detect that the soft keyboard was opened to try and do it yourself.  I'd suggest not fighting the system and using one of the above two methods.

Comment: Thanks  for the reply.  How whatsapp like app moves the edit text (not the entire window)?